# ¿Cómo divido el backend del frontend?

Tags: backend

Terminé mi página web que funciona con PHP. Ahora quiero subirla pero tengo una duda existencial. Siempre mencionan que una cosa es backend y otra cosa es frontend. Que el frontend es html y el backend en este caso seria PHP. Pero, osea no es tal así, el index.php puede ser el frontend. Mi duda es, ¿como se sube backend y frontend al hosting? Yo tengo mi página principal: index.php, un formulario: form.php, y la salida: resultado.php. En esta ultima página es donde se ejecuta un código que esta dentro de este archivo recibiendo variables de form.php por el método post. Ahora, este archivo form.php debe ir en algún lugar especial para el backend? De ser así, ya que en este archivo hay código HTML, se convertiría en el nuevo frontend? Este archivo debería ser solo como una función y luego mandarle el resultado a otra página y esta recién se muestra?
Alguien que me aclare la duda por favor, en Internet no encuentro ninguna explicación sobre ello.

Comment: El backend-frontend es una forma de arquitectura productor-consumidor. En donde la lógica de producción de datos se centraliza en un modulo (llamado back-end) y el consumidor carece de lógica de negocios, mas bien se encarga de cargar los datos y mostrarlos (frontend). Esta separación es abstracta, pues no se condice con el lugar físico donde estén guardados o su lenguaje (html, python, etc). Pueden estar tanto en servidores separados como en el mismo. Ahora esto depende como este programado, pues si programaste todo en un solo lugar (monolitico), no tienes front y back tienes todo junto.

Comment: La forma mas común de esta arquitectura es programar la lógica de negocios de una aplicación en un lenguaje de propósito general accesible mediante una API (Rest por ejemplo) y aparte programar una pagina web HTML + JS con puras request a esta API. Así la pagina web esta desacoplada de la lógica de la aplicación, pues solo hace peticiones a la API y le da estilo; y la API centraliza toda la lógica compleja utilizando usualmente algún lenguaje flexible como Python o Javascript (Por ejemplo, haciendo cálculos complejos, resolviendo consultas o corriendo redes neuronales).

Comment: Como comenta el compañero de la respuesta anterior, el FrontEnd se ejecuta en el Cliente, vale decir en tu navegador. Y el BackEnd en el Servidor, que es el que realizará tooodas las transacciones y procesos. Podrías quizás ver una opción MVC (Modelo, Vista y Controlador) para tener la lógica de tu sistema mas ordenada. En mi caso, trabajo mucho con Codeigniter me permitió manejarlo de forma mas clara. Saludos.

Comment: Viendo las respuestas, me parece que la pregunta es basada en opiniones y por ende al no mostrar un problema claro dará pie a una diversidad de soluciones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues la buena noticia es que no tienes que hacer nada:

- el back-end se ejecuta en el servidor y
- el front-end en el cliente

independientemente de en cuántos ficheros quieras separar el código.

Para entender esto, tienes que tener en cuenta que un servidor web preprocesa el PHP y el MySQL y, cuando está listo, le envía al cliente el resultado junto con el HTML, el CSS y el JS para que lo muestre en el navegador.

Si tu fichero sólo contiene front (HTML, CSS y JS), se envía tal cual al cliente.

En cambio, si contiene back (PHP o SQL), éste se procesa en el servidor y sólo se envía el resultado.

Cualquier ejemplo servirá para ilustrarlo:

```
<div style="
    background-color:lightblue;
"> Aritmética avanzada </div>

<?php echo '2+2='.(2+2); ?>
```

Código enviado al navegador (cliente):

```
<div style="
    background-color:lightblue;
"> Aritmética avanzada </div>

2+2=4
```

Que dará como resultado en pantalla:

> ```
> Aritmética avanzada
> 2+2=4
> ```

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Aunque todo esté en el mismo fichero, el CSS y el HTML simplemente se envía desde el servidor hacia el cliente. El servidor únicamente envía ese código, que será procesado en el navegador (front-end) en cuanto lo reciba.

En cambio, la parte de PHP, antes de ser enviada, se procesa en el servidor (back-end). De forma que lo que se envía es directamente un 4, la operación matemática se realiza antes de proceder al envío.

Si ese mismo cálculo lo hubieras realizado en JS (front-end), enviarías la fórmula al navegador y éste sería el encargado de realizar la operación antes de mostrarla.

Comment: Gracias David JP. Me resolviste la duda junto a los comentarios directos. Eso es lo que pensaba pero no tenia alguna documentación para corroborar, pero con la opinión de otra persona me basta.